# On whether asking "how winners spend their last moves" is on-topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I recently started playing **Caylus** on the iOS, and thought that the answer to the following problem would help me formulate a strategy and better understand the game. Note that this question could apply to many games, and indeed I have considered the answer to this question for such games as **Brass, Agricola, Princes of Florence, Le Havre** etc.

> How do players who consistently win utilize their last few moves in this game?

In Agricola, it would surely be some sort of super-efficient "fences + renovation + major improvement + family growth" combo, though we would have to factor in other players who are playing to win. Put in these worker placement games where players can acquire better/first turn order... well, I'm not sure if that simplifies things.

Anywho.

Is this question on-topic?

This is **practical**, since I play this game (!) and would be putting the answer(s) into practice against AI and human opponents.

The **problem** that I face is a lack of strategy. Sure, this is a nebulous, subjective problem to have, but a clear strategy will solve it.

I would like others to explain [this] to me.

Comment: I feel like you're better off asking the question than asking a meta-question about asking the question. I don't like the "[closed]" tag, either, but nothing bad actually happens when a good-faith question is closed.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in [Considering the number of strategy questions, should we write specific scope limitations for strategy questions?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/considering-the-number-of-strategy-questions-should-we-write-specific-scope-lim) , strategy questions are encouraged and appreciated by the Board and Card Games community, so long as they are reasonably scoped. For example, the question:

> What are good chess strategies?

is too broad. End game strategy can be reasonably scoped for many games, though I think adding some context is often warranted. For example, your question just inspired me to post a Settlers end game question I have sometimes wondered about:

[What is optimal end play in Settlers?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/what-is-optimal-end-play-in-settlers)