# About probability - understanding the scope for a future question

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I was reading the info about [probability](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) tag, which I quote:

> Questions about probabilistic game mechanics and **how to calculate and estimate random events**, as well as how probability affects games and gameplay.

I'm wondering *if* I can make a question focused on the highlighted text above.

What I would try question is:

**How can I calculate the probability for get all cards of Exodia, the Forbidden One taken from my Deck at Draw phase** - Yu-Gi-Oh! TCG

All some of you may know, but my question is focused according to draw cards from my Deck without using another ways for get these cards.

---

By the way, I made my question here in Meta for get feedback about if my question could add value to Board & Card Games site *(and, of course, if my question could be on-topic, after read days ago [these](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/408/15297) [answers](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/655/15297) in Meta)*.

Comment: If you're unsure whether a question is allowed, just ask it. In the worst case, it gets closed, and nothing bad happens. And in this case, if there's a tag specifically about the kind of question you want to ask, it's a good bet that you are allowed to ask it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go ahead and ask, we've got several similar questions already.

In general, the advice murgatroid gave is perfect.  Ask whatever question you want on the main site.  If a question gets closed, and you don't understand why, then taking it to meta is a good way to go.

Comment: Thank you @@Pat Ludwig and @@murgattroid99. [I posted my question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/29096/15297) and I share the link in this comment because maybe my question would need some edit about sintaxis. Thanks.